# Frequentist's stochastic modelling via Python

Tags: modeling, python, optimization, frequentist

Consider random variables $X$ and $Y$. $Z = f_a(X, Y)$ where $f(\cdot, \cdot)$ is a deterministic, not random function $f_a: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ depending on a deterministic real parameter $a$. For example, let  $f_a(X,Y)=aX+(1-a)Y$.

I've read a lot about Bayesian modelling and fitting with the help of `pymc3` Python module. But how can I model $Z$ in a frequentist's manner? I am to calculate quantiles, optimize $a$ over setting $\mathbb{E}Z$ to $0$ etc.

What is the most convinient way to do this? I haven't found solution neither in `scipy.optimize` nor `scipy.stats`.

Comment: Would you specify what the deterministic function is, please? It might give the question a broader appeal if more of us understand it.

Comment: actually, any function. I try to find a general approach. Let, e.g. $f_a(X, Y) = aX + (1-a) Y$.

Comment: OK, in that case the Bayesian priors would likely be independent for $X$ and $Y$ because there is no $XY$ covariance term and iff $0<a<1$, $aX+(1-a)Y$ is a mixture distribution, for which two independent processes are adding to the density. In other words, there are two distributions with no convolution chaining or cross-talk that are mixed with superpositioning to make final density function. With a different form, for example with an $XY$ term, that would not necessarily be the case, such that I am guessing that it may be necessary to divide up the problem into special cases.

Comment: @Carl my question is mainly about Python modeling. I don't need to fit my model, I need to optimize distribution parameter $a$

Comment: I know how to do that with fitting, I do not know how without fitting. I would use Tikhonov regularization error propagation of $a$ adaptively minimized for the error, or relative error of $a$.

Comment: @Carl could you write it in detail?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45332/discussion-between-carl-and-denis-korzhenkov).

Comment: @Carl: do you want to post your comment(s) as an answer? [Better to have a short answer than no answer at all.](https://stats.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5326/1352) Anyone who has a better answer can post it.

Comment: @StephanKolassa As per your request, posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

OK, in that case the Bayesian priors would likely be independent for  and  because there is no  covariance term and iff 0<<1, +(1−) is a mixture distribution, for which two independent processes are adding to the density. In other words, there are two distributions with no convolution chaining or cross-talk that are mixed with superpositioning to make final density function. With a different form, for example with an  term, that would not necessarily be the case, such that I am guessing that it may be necessary to divide up the problem into special cases.

I would use Tikhonov regularization error propagation of  adaptively minimized for the error, or relative error of .